# How to create a graph with two bars and a line in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am try to get this outcome:
[image]

This is my df:

```
 df<-  structure(list(Date = structure(c(18319, 18320, 18321, 18322, 
18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 18329, 18330, 18331, 
18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 
18341, 18342, 18343), class = "Date"), Daily_Cases = c(250, 238, 
240, 566, 342, 466, 587, 769, 778, 1247, 1492, 1797, 977, 2313, 
2651, 2547, 3497, 3590, 3233, 3526, 4207, 5322, 5986, 6557, 5560
), Tests = c(2427, 3681, 2966, 2466, 2218, 2511, 3981, 2525, 
3997, 5703, 7875, 3889, 6935, 12393, 12857, 11477, 11682, 15729, 
13063, 10695, 16884, 17236, 24109, 26336, 25180), Proportion = c(10.3, 
6.5, 8.1, 23, 15.4, 18.6, 14.7, 30.5, 19.5, 21.9, 18.9, 46.2, 
14.1, 18.7, 20.6, 22.2, 29.9, 22.8, 24.7, 33, 24.9, 30.9, 24.8, 
24.9, 22.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

**Proportion** is the black line, **Tests** the grey bars and **Daily_Cases** the red bars. I tried any of the codes only (applied to my cases) but I don't manage to do it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really help us helping you - what you want to achieve requires a lot of things that need to be implemented. Please focus on one problem per question.

Here to make the graph.

Problems:

- make your data long
- Use geom_col and position_dodge
- rescale your proportion data
- **For secondary y-axis,** consider all the many threads here on SO. (e.g. [ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales))

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18319, 18320, 18321, 18322, 
                                  18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 18329, 18330, 18331, 
                                  18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 
                                  18341, 18342, 18343), class = "Date"), Daily_Cases = c(250, 238, 
                                                                                         240, 566, 342, 466, 587, 769, 778, 1247, 1492, 1797, 977, 2313, 
                                                                                         2651, 2547, 3497, 3590, 3233, 3526, 4207, 5322, 5986, 6557, 5560
                                  ), Tests = c(2427, 3681, 2966, 2466, 2218, 2511, 3981, 2525, 
                                               3997, 5703, 7875, 3889, 6935, 12393, 12857, 11477, 11682, 15729, 
                                               13063, 10695, 16884, 17236, 24109, 26336, 25180), Proportion = c(10.3, 
                                                                                                                6.5, 8.1, 23, 15.4, 18.6, 14.7, 30.5, 19.5, 21.9, 18.9, 46.2, 
                                                                                                                14.1, 18.7, 20.6, 22.2, 29.9, 22.8, 24.7, 33, 24.9, 30.9, 24.8, 
                                                                                                                24.9, 22.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))


mydf_long <- mydf %>% pivot_longer(names_to = 'key', values_to = 'value', Tests:Daily_Cases)

ggplot(mydf_long) + 
  geom_col(aes(Date, value, fill = key), position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(Date, Proportion *1000, group = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks so much! Sorry I wasn't precise enough. I understood a lot now from your solution. Thanks again